# AngularJS: How to login once and do not need to login again

Tags: angularjs, rest, authentication, service

I have implemented the authentication/authorization using AngularJS, Jersey REST and Spring Security. After logged in, call the following "create" method to store the user information:

```
.factory('Session', function () {
    this.create = function (user) {
        this.id = user.sessionId;
        this.username = user.username;
        this.userRoles = user.roles;
    };

    ... ...

    return this;
})
```

But, the problem is, every time I do one of the following 2 things, the stored information is lost and I have to login again:

- Reload the whole page by pressing F5 or reload icon of browser
  OR
- Access the same URL from browser address bar

Could you please help me on how to reserve this information to guarantee login only once?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage). Not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but presumably your controller could save the Session created by your factory into sessionStorage.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helped me out even I pick the sessionStorage in [ngStorage](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage) instead.